# How long do Asgardians live for?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel

Thor has been visiting the Earth from the time of the Norse Vikings. What is the expected life span (in Earth years) of an Agardian?

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asgard_%28comics%29#The_six_races) on Asgard only states:

> They are extremely long-lived (though not truly immortal like the Olympians), aging at an extremely slow rate upon reaching adulthood (through the periodic consumption of the golden apples of Idunn).

Comment: To mix references without mercy: it depends on how well they can wedge the dagger in the wall and if they can work up a *really* good fling or not.

Comment: To steal from the other major sci-fi Asgard, maybe they just clone themselves every couple hundred years and transfer their consciousness into a new body.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### [Marvel's Comics Asgardians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asgard_%28comics%29) were considered functionally immortal. They aged very slowly upon reaching adulthood (unlike Marvel's Olympians, who do not age AT ALL) and as such would live until killed. While the [Golden Apples of Idunn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_apple#Norse_mythology) are discussed in Marvel's Asgard, no mechanics for their processes are described.

[image: The Asgardians in their most popular appearances]

*The Asgardians in their most famous guises over the decades.*

The difference between functional immortality and actually immortality would mean nothing to us, if their span of years numbered in the thousands. Since the myths of Norse mythology have included beings such as Odin since the 11th century, Odin would be at least 1,000 years old. He is likely much older.

[image]

*This image denotes Marvel's official position on the Asgardians as aliens.
From **Thor #493** (written by Warren Ellis and Mike Deodato)*

**Things to be remembered about Marvel's Asgardians:**

- Marvel's Asgardians were based on the deities of Norse myths of old. But they are not those deities.
- They are an advanced species of humanoids who resemble humans and have technologies so advanced they appear as magic to humans.
- They are extremely long-lived as a species and have superhuman levels of strength, vigor and physical vitality. As such, myths may not take into account the actual capabilities of these beings.
- While they consume the Golden Apples of Idunn, the actual mechanics of how those Apples work have not been defined in the comics, only expressed in myths and legends.
- Most Asgardians expected to survive until Ragnarok, with the occasional death of lesser gods at the hands of their powerful enemies such as the Frost Giants or Fire Giants.

Comment: What do the images have to do with your answer?

Comment: I do not make the assumption, a person asking the question has ever seen images of what they are requesting (image 1) That picture shows popular versions of Marvel's Asgardians over a wide swath of time. Since comics are a visual medium, if there are images that can help substantiate the information I am relaying, I do that (image 2). Take the time to read image 2 and you can read Marvel's official stance on the Asgardians as a reference canon of the Asgardians as aliens.

Comment: “But they are not those deities” can be read two ways: that Marvel altered the mythology so deeply that one can't reliably infer much about one from the other; or, more weirdly, that the old Norse of Earth-616 met some *other* batch of ‘gods’ and based a mythology (more like our timeline's) on them. Which?

Answer (score 5):

Well, simply put about 5100 years. Loki commented this to Odin in "Thor: The Dark World" when Odin said they were not gods, but lived and died just as humans did. Loki said "give or take 5000 years". So if the average human lives to be around 80 or so, then an Asgardian would live to be about 5100.

Answer (score 2):

That scan that was taken from Thor # 493 by Warren Ellis does not denote Marvel's official position on the nature of the Asgardians existence or lifespan. At most, that scan depicts writter Warren Ellis' ill-informed position, as there are decades worth of Thor continuity that more than solidified his place as an actual god. That comic is simply inconsistent.

An alien, or "extra terrestrial", generally refers to a natural born biological being from another planet in our universe apart from Earth.

The Asgardian race predates the universe. As depicted in Thor # 85, as well as several other Thor comics, Odin created the world as we know it. His lifespan has already exceed BILLIONS of years, considering he presided over the creation of Mjolnir which KILLED THE DINOSAURS.

These beings are not aliens from another planet, they're entities that exist in a dimension above our own, and created the world, including human beings. In short: They Are Gods.

Marvel makes a big difference betweenn the scientifically explainable aliens of thier universe and the gods and demons that are of divine/magical energy and origin.

Comment: Where does your info on Mjolnir killing the dinosaurs come from?!?

Answer (score 1):

Thor did mention in *Avengers: Infinity War* that he's lived for about 1500 years. He is still what would be the equivalent of a late 20s to early 30 year old, so I would guess between 6-10000 years old unless they have some other power influencing them.

Comment: Thanks Madman - that would be the MCU take. And I am guessing 6 - 10 k years!