# What was the ultimate origin of Asgardians?

Tags: marvel, asgardians

According to [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Asgardians):

> The Gods are the most human looking and believed to have inhabited Earth at one time only to move to Asgard sometime later.

If they originated on Earth, what are they evolutionary speaking? Human mutants? Aliens that made home on earth more than millenia(s) ago? Aliens from other dimensions (since they moved to Asgard which is in another dimension, it would be plausible).

*I'm looking for canon answer, from the comics (I can accept info from the movies, but not if it contradicts any comics info)*.

Comment: Are you asking for the origin of Asgardians in the Marvel [Ultimate universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel) specifically?

Comment: @BennyMcBenBen - Truth be told, I'm too much of a clueless newbie to know the difference.

Comment: From where did you get that Asgard is in another dimension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Marvel has never given the planets or dimensions of origin of any of its "divine" beings. They are and have been depicted as entities/aliens descended somehow from the Earthforces called [Gaea](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix/gaeathor.htm) and [Atum](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix/atum.htm#Demiurge), and who take on the guises of "gods" during their early interactions with humanity. All we are know is the [Asgardians](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16815/2765) and other deities live in nearby dimensional realms protecting the Earth from cosmic threats.

The first gathering of the [**Council of Godheads**](http://marvel.wikia.com/Council_of_Godheads_%28Earth-616%29), to combat the imminent threat of the alien Celestials, in Thor #300:

[image]

Most of what we know of the origins of the Skyfather deities isn't revealed until the return of the Celestials who plan to destroy the Earth if they didn't find it worthy. The Skyfathers of all of Earth's major pantheons get together with Odin and attempt to (unsuccessfull) repel the Celestials. Until then, we were given no indication of who, how or why these beings were on Earth.

Marvel later again confirms the Asgardians (and by proxy, all other deities) were "not from around here" and were aliens who lived on Earth far in the past, alongside humans. There are many later depictions of this Council of Godheads who explain their relationships with humanity and stand as defenders of the Earth, removed from worship or regular interference with Earthly affairs.

Comment: What is `**` at the end of your first paragraph meant to signify? I assumed it would be a footnote, but none came.

Comment: @Thaddeus Howze, I thought all the gods belonging to the pantheons of Earth have their origin ultimately rooted in the Demiurge, is that not the case anymore?