# Would Hydra's weapons in Captain America have been effective against Asgardians?

Tags: weapon, asgardians

As established [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18036/1234), human firearms have no effect against Thor, Loki and other Asgardians. Between an Asgardians's powerful armor, dense body and other technological advantages, a standard bullet doesn't have a chance.

It stands to reason then, that something similarly powerful would be required to effectively combat an Asgardian. In that case, would the weapons that HYDRA developed in the [2011 Captain America movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458339/) have been any more effective against Asgardians, considering the power source used (the [Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Cube#Film))? Or would these weapons still have been too primitive, despite the origin of their power?

Comment: Wasn't that the whole point of everyone being mad at Fury? That he was using the Tesseract to create weapons to fight the new kind of wars they were getting themselves into?

Comment: @NominSim While it is true that Fury was weaponizing the Terreract, his intention was to use it to fight extra-Earth enemies, not other nations on earth. So SHIELD's weapons would have been built with more advance defenses in mind, not to mention the advances in technology from the 1940s to the 2010s.

Comment: Sorry I should have expanded the comment a bit and just made it into an answer in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In The Avengers movie Fury is doing just what you say: using the Tesseract to create weapons that will be powerful enough to fight the extraterrestrial forces that they have encountered(namely Loki and friends). One would have to assume that since that was the purpose of his development that they would have been powerful enough to "effectively combat an Asgardian".

Since the weapons he was creating were based on the same technology as the Hydra weapons, it should be safe for us to assume that yes they would have been effective against Asgardians.

Comment: Correction: We can safely assume it was *thought* they would be effective against the Asgardians, there's no way to know for sure.  Fury preferred the Avengers Initiative, though, he wasn't happy about the tesseract weaponry.

Comment: @Jeff don't forget that Agent Coulson actually does use a weapon created with the Tesseract technology against Loki, and it seems to be effective(it isn't blocked). The assumption is more along the lines of whether the HYDRA weapons would have been as effective (and since they are the same technology etc. the assumption is yes).

Comment: Not to be a Johnny-come-lately, but the weapon fired by Agent Coulson was based on The Destroyer, as seen in "Thor".