# Do the Asgardians have healing devices, magic, or potions?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In the MCU, Asgardians refer to some of the things they can do as magic. Other beings refer to it as magic too. Magic, or advanced science, is usually depicted as having the ability to heal the sick and the wounded. However, in the MCU, we don't see many examples of healing magic, or healing science.

If the Asgardians are always fighting, it would make more sense for them to be able to heal their wounded in the field, for example, with healing potions. In *Thor: The Dark World*, as well as *Thor: Ragnarok*, we see many Asgardians die and no first aid rendered to them.

Do the Asgardians have any healing magic, abilities, or devices?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**

- Moved to answer for potential spoilers...
- Of course they do; we just don't know what...

They do, but I don't think we know much about it. If we knew what they did to heal we would likely consider it to be magic of some sort. There are two things we know for sure about.

They use a "[Soul Forge](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/b/b5/Soulforge.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20161108060451)" to diagnose illnesses and that somehow the "Odin Sleep" kept Odin alive for a little bit longer than is typical.

Beyond this I do not think we know much. I can not remember any points in the MCU or comics where an Asgardian pulled out a med-kit or anything. However from Ragnarok we do know:

> Thor and Loki used to play "Get Help" where Thor would be dragging Loki (and then he may have thrown Loki at them?!) likely to distract guards or something when they were younger - From this we know that Asgardians do help the wounded and that there are procedures in place to help those that are hurt.

Towards the afterlife, we know:

> Thor also said a prayer for his father after he passed stating that he would go to Valhalla - This tells us that they believe in an afterlife and that (if it follows typical Norse mytho) dying on the battlefield is the best way to die. Saving someone from that fate could be seen as an insult? Maybe they allow the warriors to fall out of respect.

Comment: well, who could answer it better than the all-father Odin himself :p

Answer (score 0):

As your question is based on the MCU version of Asgardians, I will base my answers on the same.

Asgardians are god-like beings and superior to humans both technologically as well as physically. Some of their physical abilities (as mentioned [here](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Asgardians) on the Marvel-Movies Wikia) are:

> ***Super Density***: The Asgardians' molecular structure is denser than Humans. This contributes to their super strength and durability. The materials of Asgard are denser then those of Earth, as is mentioned with Asgardian metals, used to make many items for the use of Asgardians such as their swords and armor. The denser, stronger materials of Asgard are the reason why Asgardians themselves are denser.
>
> ***Accelerated Healing***: Even though Asgardians are resistant to injury, if they do get hurt they heal remarkablily quickly. ***Elliot Randolph survived a fatal blow with very limited medical attention, and Thor healed from Loki stabbing him in the gut with a knife quite quickly.***
>
> ***Longevity***: Asgardians have an extremely long life span and can endure for thousands of years. Some can regenerate and extend their lifespan by magical means. (***e.g. When Odin enters the Odinsleep***).

And speaking of their physiology:

> Asgardians resemble humans of Caucasian and African descent while their sister race, the Vanir, resemble humans of Asian descent. ***Their body tissues are three times as dense as that of humans which contributes to their superhuman strength and durability***. They heal remarkably quickly and can even recover from fatal blows. They live for an average of five thousand years due to their healing abilities. Their blood is red, like humans. While able to withstand human strength blows and even human-made projectiles, they can be wounded with Earthly weapons, given enough strength by the user or force of the projectile.

The "magic" referred to by the Asgardians is actually a type of energy manipulation that is not yet invented/discovered by humans ([find the details here](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Asgardians)).

So, their superior body and dense body tissues are helpful to take on heavy blows. While their accelerated healing power is quite useful in battles. However, speaking about a normal Asgardian and comparing him with the likes of Thor Odinson or Loki etc., you can find the answer for that [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55697/how-strong-are-asgardians) (comic-book explanation). For more details on Asgardian medical technology, feel free to check [this](https://forum.gateworld.net/threads/66340-Asgard-Medical-Technologies?s=a7162f00eb4f0009f72e9cef9a12d672).

Comment: While this is a great answer regarding their physiology what does this answer have to do with their medical practices? And that very last link goes to a Stargate SG1 website talking about the Asgard race within the Stargate universe... those are completely different than MCU Asgards...