# Why was Thor going to be made king if Odin is immortal?

Tags: marvel, avengers, thor-marvel

Why was Thor going to be made king if Odin is immortal?

According to legend, the Odin Father is the keeper of the Odin Force, and must enter the Odin Sleep once a year to retain his power ... we see a pattern here that Odin is somewhat important. Additionally, some legend says that Asgard survives and maintains it's splendor specifically because of the Odin Force, which is only maintained by the will of Odin. So if he is going to always be around (for Asgard to persist per the previous legends), is Odin merely a title, or is there something more important about Odin that he will persist even if Thor replaces him? Odin does seem to be a little invincible after all.

Was the title merely hereditary and each Odin passed the title before dying or is there another reason for Odin passing the title?

Comment: Were they truly immortal though? I thought Demigods could be killed by each other in battle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long do Asgardians live for?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16783/how-long-do-asgardians-live-for)

Comment: The Asgardians are functionally immortal as long as they eat the Apples of Indunn. But they can be killed in battle and have protocols for succession.

Comment: It's also important to remember that immortal is not the same thing as invincible. There is always the possibility of Odin being killed in battle or just being too ill or frail to govern.

Comment: I've always thought that Thor would become king while Odin sleeps.

Comment: Odin is not the title, AllFather is the title, Odin is the god (not demi-god) who holds the title of AllFather, which he was going to pass on to Thor

Comment: Ooooh, then why is everything called "odinxxxxxxx"? Does he pass on the Odin Force (for example) to Thor? Will Thor now require Odinsleep? (I realize I'm branching the question by asking this, but not sure how much of it belongs in a new question...

Comment: And if Odin is a god, how is Thor a demi-god?

Comment: @jcolebrand he's only referred to as a demi-god in the movie (which I suspect is out of political correctness as they tried not to draw too many religious comparisons) in all other media he's explicitly referred to as a god. i.e. the God of Thunder

Comment: It's referred to as Odinsleep because Odin is the one doing the hibernation.  If it where Thor, or another god who needed to hibernate to replenish his energies it would be the Thorsleep.

Comment: I thought even Marvel at times only called Thor a demi-god? (hey, this is the place for me to ask :p so I'll ask :D )

Comment: The Odin Force however would always be referred to as such, because it's almost elemental in nature.  Odin created it, and therefore named it, he controls it, but he can give it to someone else, but it's still the same force so it retains the name.

Comment: ooooh, good info to have. Not sure if those wrap up into a contiguous question here, but I like the trains of thought. :D

Comment: I'm surprised that no one mentioned the fact that Marvel's version of Asgardians are NOT immortal at all - just extremely long-lived.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because the Norse Gods have to go through a little thing called Ragnarok. Basically, the real myths of the norse are set forth in the [Eddas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddas) and in them, Odin and Thor are both fated to die after slaying great foes. In the Marvel universe, only Odin is fated to die in that battle. Thor gains control of the Odinforce and is driven slightly insane by it, which is covered in the trades: 
The Death of Odin,
The Lord of Asgard,
Gods on Earth,
Spiral,
The Reigning, and
Gods and Men.

Thor does have to sleep to retain control of this power, the same as Odin had to, although he can still use his own power whenever he wants. He later uses the power to recreate Valhalla on Earth, although that last might have been retcon'd as I haven't kept up lately with the story line.

The reason that it is present in the movies is, I suspect, that Thor doesn't really have a lot of stuff to hang a story on. His comic book has always been a little less character driven that the other Marvel properties because he isn't really a part of this world and doesn't really want to fit into it anyway.

Comment: +1, even though I found the last paragraph questionable :)

Comment: The trades mentioned cover the end of *THOR* volume 2 (circa 2003-2006 or thereabouts), and are a *specific iteration* of Ragnarok. And, in fact, only the very end of that run (the last storyline, and thus the last trade) was truly Ragnarok; Odin "died" (he's come back since, at least once) before Ragnarok, which led to the events mentioned. Marvel has shown Ragnarok multiple times before (*THOR* volume 1, 200 (recounting of myths); 273-278 (a version of Ragnarok; Asgard does not get wiped out); and elsewhere). And, Odin has "died" other times (most notably during the Simonson run).

Answer (score 4):

> We are not gods. We're born, we live, we die, just as humans do.

--Odin, *Thor: The Dark World*

The short answer is simply that the Asgardians are not immortal.

Unfortunately, we do not know enough about the Odinforce and the Odinsleep in the MCU to extrapolate further on those subjects.

Comment: This depends on the definition of "immortal". Some would look upon this as someone *cannot* die; others, as someone cannot die *by natural causes*, still others as someone is simply so long-lived that, to humans, they are *practically* immortal. Asgardians presumably fall in the second or third category.

Comment: I agree that it comes to semantics, but Odin's phrasing ("as humans do") makes me inclined to believe they're the third category.